# Send GET variables without reloading the page with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

What I am trying to do is run a `GET` request in javascript when a download link is pressed. When the link is pressed it would send a `GET` request to a php script that basically counts how many times the link is pressed. Here is my code but I can't seem to get it to work right. I'm pretty new to javascript but still know my way around. I have tested and My getrulvars() function works and my function when a link is pressed works so I am sure that its my GET request that it not working

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m, key, value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
// Wait for page to load
window.onload = function() {
    var a = document.getElementById("downloadLink");
    var app = getUrlVars()["app"];

    a.onclick = function() {    
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "download_count.php?app=" + app, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you done any basic debugging? Check that `app` is the value you expect? That your geturlvars() function is even working? We're good, but we're not psychic. "Can't get it to work" is **NOT** useful. **HOW** it doesn't work is far better information to share

Comment: @MarcB Yes my geturlvars() function is working and the triggering javascript is working when the link is pressed so I'm pretty sure that the issue is with sending the GET info.

Comment: @Jonathan Where do you lose sight of your `GET` variable? Can you even `echo` it in PHP? Could this be an issue with your PHP script rather than your JS?

Comment: @F4r-20 My php script it working I have tested it. My getrulvars() function works and my function when a link is pressed works so I am sure that its my GET request that it not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it working what I had to do is return false then in my php script have it download the file. I guess when I was downloading the file it wouldn't allow the jQuery to send the GET value.